# Unwanted character being added to string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcat

I have a program that gives you shipping addresses from an input file.  However at the beginning of one of the strings, order.add_one, a number is being added to the beginning of the string, that number is equivalent to the variable "choice" every time.  Why is it doing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

//structure
typedef struct
{char cust_name[25];
 char cust_id[3];
 char add_one[30];
 char add_two[30];
 char bike;
 char risky;
 int number_ordered;
 char cust_information[500];
 }ORDER;

 ORDER order;

int main(void){
fflush(stdin);
system ( "clear" );



        FILE *fpt;
        fpt = fopen("input.txt", "r");

            if (fpt==NULL){
                printf("Text file did not open\n");
                return 1;
                }

                printf("Enter Customer ID: ");
                scanf("%s", &order.cust_id);

                char choice;
                choice = order.cust_id[0];

                char x[3];
                int w, u, y, z;  
                char a[10], b[10], c[10], d[10], e[20], f[10], g[10], i[1], j[1];
                int h;
                printf("%s value of c", c);

                if (choice >='1'){
            while  ((w = fgetc(fpt)) != '\n' ){
            }
            }
                if (choice >='2'){
                while  ((u = fgetc(fpt)) != '\n' ){
                }
                }
                if (choice >='3'){
                while  ((y = fgetc(fpt)) != '\n' ){
                }
                }
                if (choice >= '4'){
                while  ((z = fgetc(fpt)) != '\n' ){
                }
                }
                printf("\n");
                fscanf(fpt, "%s", x);

                    fscanf(fpt, "%s", a);
                    printf("%s", a);
                    strcat(order.cust_name, a);

                    fscanf(fpt, " %s", b);
                    printf(" %s", b);
                    strcat(order.cust_name, " ");
                   strcat(order.cust_name, b);

                    fscanf(fpt, "%s", c);
                    printf(" %s", c);
                    strcat(order.add_one, "\0");
                    strcat(order.add_one, c);

                    fscanf(fpt, "%s", d);
                    printf(" %s", d);
                    strcat(order.add_one, " ");
                    strcat(order.add_one, d);

                    fscanf(fpt, "%s", e);
                    printf(" %s", e);
                    strcat(order.add_two, e);

                    fscanf(fpt, "%s", f);
                    printf(" %s", f);
                    strcat(order.add_two, " ");
                    strcat(order.add_two, f);

                    fscanf(fpt, "%s", g);
                    printf(" %s", g);
                    strcat(order.add_two, " ");
                    strcat(order.add_two, g);
                    strcat(order.add_two, "\0");

                    fscanf(fpt, "%d", &h);
                    printf(" %d", h);
                    order.number_ordered = h;

                    fscanf(fpt, "%s", i);
                    printf(" %s", i);
                    order.bike = i[0];

                    fscanf(fpt, "%s", j);
                    printf(" %s", j);   
                   order.risky = j[0];
                  fclose(fpt);

                  printf("%s %s %s %d %c %c", order.cust_name, order.add_one, order.add_two, order.number_ordered, order.bike, order.risky);
            }
```

Comment: You need to narrow down your error - it is not acceptable to post an entire program and have us do the research of isolating what is going wrong.

Comment: Which of your hundred `printf` statements is showing the error?

Comment: Also `1==1` looks like [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). You should really try to understand what statements are doing rather than just copying what has worked before.. It will make your life much easier.

Comment: What data are you entering into the program when you get the error?

Comment: The array `c` is not initialised when you print it in the `printf("%s",c)` statement.

Comment: The data comes from a text file, "c" should be 320 if the user's choice is equal to "1", but "c" ends up being "1320"

Comment: And sorry for the lengthy post, I didn't want to leave out something that was important that I didn't catch, shortened it down a bit.

Comment: Where is the code where `c` gets assigned?

Comment: The data file is a must...  without it the program simply returns.  With an empty `input.txt` it simply prints ` value of c` and ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a major error:

```
char ..., i[1], ...

...

fscanf(fpt, "%s", i);
```

This call to `fscanf` will *overwrite* other memory, even if it's only reading one character `fscanf` *adds* a second characters, the special string termination character `'\0'`.

If you have sized the other arrays at *exactly* the size of the fields in the input file, then this will happen for all your input.